# pyqt4 - QTimer stops when close button is held

Tags: python, events, pyqt4

I'm writing an application in pyqt4 that displays the time remaining for the user to do something on a main window. I'm using Qt5.5 and pyqt4 with python 2.7.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.time = 120
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 170, 500, 550))
        self.displayTime()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1100, 850)
        # Do other stuff
    def displayTime(self):
        minute, sec = divmod(self.time,60)
        self.lcdNumber.display('{}:{:02d}'.format(minute,sec))
    def updateTime(self):
        self.time -= 1
        self.displayTime()
        if self.time == 0:
            self.timer.stop()

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWin()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works the way I expected, but when the user click the close button without releasing it, he is able to stop the timer, while he can still see what's on the window. The problem seems to be only on Windows.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce: I held the close button and the timer keeps going. I'm on Linux, PyQt 4.11.4

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this (on Linux). What plaform are you on, and what versions of Qt/PyQt are you using?

Comment: After I saw your comments I tried on Linux and you are right, it's working perfectly fine. The problem comes from windows. I'm using qt5.5 with pyqt4

Answer (score 0):

According to this Qt Forum thread:

- [QTimer events not executed when holding minimize/maximize/close button](http://forum.qt.io/topic/55416/qtimer-events-not-executed-when-holding-minimize-maximize-close-button)

this is "normal" behaviour on Windows. Basically, pressing and holding any of the title-bar buttons kills all event-processing until the button is released.

It is suggested that a thread is used instead of a timer. But in your case this probably won't help, because you would need to emit a signal to update the GUI, and cross-thread signals also need a running event-loop.

So perhaps you should use a [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) [timer](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/timer.html) with a callback, instead.